# Integrate external angular2 widgets into main angular2 project

Tags: angular, architecture

I have a core angular4 application which would act as a container application which would load externally built angular4 widgets/applications.

We have multiple teams who would build their own widgets which we would want to include in the main application.

But as per my current analysis I could not find any example of such a scenario.

So I just wanted to know whether it is possible to load external angular4 applications into a main angular4 application? I know it is possible to build components and load them similar to primeng. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Just create a package with widgets and import it, like you would do with any other NPM package that contains Angular widgets. For example https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Thank you for the input. so once i import the widget, I should update the app.module file in the core application and it should work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You need to add the module with the widgets to `@NgModule({ ..., imports: [MyWidgetModule]}) class MyModule {}` to every module where you want to use widgets of `MyWidgetModule`.

Comment: See also https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules, https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq